# Problema al cambiar a https

Tags: php, wordpress, video

Hola he cambiado mi web a https y los vídeos que tengo a través de wowza no consigo verlos. Tengo una lista de reproducción y aparece primero un video de cabecera y luego el vídeo solicitado sin que este se vea, el de cabecera si. El error que me indica es: Este archivo de video no se puede reproducir. (Código de Error: 232011) En el log de wowza me da el siguiente mensaje:

> HTTPStreamerAdapterCupertinoStreamer.onPlaylist: No se cargó el contexto de la aplicación [ //playlist.m3u8 ]: defapp / definst

y el código que tengo en wordpress es:

```
        if ($embed)
         { ?>


        <div id='container<?=$post->ID;?>'><a href="rtsp://<?php echo $ipstream; ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "base_url_video_streaming_rtmp", true); ?>/<?php echo $embed;?><?php if ($extension == 'null') { echo ''; } else { echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "formato_archivo_de_video_streaming_rtmp", true); } ?>">Enlace</a></div>           
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('container<?=$post->ID;?>').setup({
        autostart: "false",
        /*flashplayer: "<?php bloginfo ('url');?>/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",*/
        playlist: [ { image: "<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {echo  $large_image_url[0];} else {if($img) { echo content_url(); echo "/"; echo $img;} else { echo bloginfo('template_directory'); echo '/images/preview.jpg';}}?>", sources: [{ file:"rtmp://<?php echo $ipstream; ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "base_url_cabecera", true); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "archivo_cabecera_streaming", true); ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "formato_archivo_cabecera_streaming", true); ?>" },{ file:"https://<?php echo $ipstream; ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "base_url_cabecera", true); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "archivo_cabecera_streaming", true); ?>/playlist.m3u8" }]},
                { image: "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "url_imagen_preview", true); ?>", sources: [{ file:"rtmps://<?php echo $ipstream; ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "base_url_video_streaming_rtmp", true); ?>/<?php echo $embed;?><?php if ($extension == 'null') { echo ''; } else { echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "formato_archivo_de_video_streaming_rtmp", true); } ?>" },{ file:"https://<?php echo $ipstream; ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "base_url_video_streaming_https", true); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_streaming_https", true); ?>/playlist.m3u8" }]<?php if ($sub == 'true') {echo ',
                tracks: [{
                file:"https://', $ipstream,'/', get_post_meta($post->ID, "base_url_video_streaming_https", true),'/', get_post_meta($post->ID, "nombre_subtitulo", true),  get_post_meta($post->ID, "formato_subtitulo", true),'",
                label: "', get_post_meta($post->ID, "descripcion_subtitulo", true),'",
                kind: "captions",
                "default": true 
                }]';}?>
        }],
        width: 640,
        height: 360,
        androidhls:"true",
        primary: "html5",
        logo: { file: '<?php bloginfo ('url');?>/jwplayer/logo.png', link: '<?php bloginfo ('url');?>' },
        androidhls: true
        });
        </script>
```

Lo probé con el protocolo `rtmps` pero nada, e incluso quitandolo. Por favor no soy programadora, mi nivel es mínimo, desearía ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Entonces esto es de wordpress? Si es asi especifica en las etiquetas

Comment: Quizá tengas que hacer cambios desde wowza, para que permita conexiones basadas en `https`, revisa [este artículo](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-connect-to-wowza-streaming-engine-manager-over-https) en la documentación.

Comment: Cambiaste a https desde configuracion -> general?

Comment: Prueba colocando aqui el HTML resultante de procesar tu PHP, nos ayudará mas a conocer el problema.  Por otro lado el uso de HTTPS no suele ser el problema, sino mezclar contenidos HTTPS y HTTP,  cuando visitas un sitio desde HTTPS el navegador por seguridad bloqueará los contenidos solicitados bajo HTTP

Comment: Comprueba desde la consola de desarrollador si tienes errores o advertencias, y en la pestaña Network podras ver bajo que protocolo están viajando tus archivos, suma atención a los que se involucran con tu problema.